# How to Select Columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, multiple-columns

I have a csv file with 5 columns; I want to select the 4th column using the index of that column (so it would be 3). How can I print all values in that column in Jupyter notebook using pandas? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) to access the column by its index (which is a zero based index)

```
df.iloc[:,3]
```